# Android ConstraintLayout - how to set margins of chain_packed elements programmatically

Tags: java, android, margins, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

This is my code:

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(40,105);
buttonParams.setMargins(8,16,24,32);
secretCodeFields = findViewById(R.id.secretCodeFields);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    vID[i]=View.generateViewId();
    b.setId(vID[i]);
    b.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

    secretCodeFields.addView(b);
}
set.clone(secretCodeFields);
set.createHorizontalChain(
    secretCodeFields.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,
    secretCodeFields.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
    vID,null,ConstraintSet.CHAIN_PACKED
    );
set.applyTo(secretCodeFields);
```

Buttons are added in the same place (so only last one is visible). The same resultat if I delete "b.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);" line and use

```
secretCodeFields.addView(b,buttonParams);
```

[image: All buttons in one place]

But if I add button with width and height params it works, but there are no more margins:

```
secretCodeFields.addView(b,90,90);
```

[image: Buttons in chain but without margins]

What I do wrong?

EDIT:
secretCodeFields is ConstraintLayout

I found solution. I added margins AFTER set.applyTo... :

```
for (int i = 0; i < codeLenght; i++) {
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(vID[i]);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams p = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) b.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(6,0,6,0);
        b.setLayoutParams(p);
    }
```

It works, but I don't know if it is the best solution.

Comment: Why don't you try `ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID` instead of `view.getId()`?

Comment: I think that it's the same in this case. I changed this for
"set.createHorizontalChain(
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                vID,null,ConstraintSet.CHAIN_PACKED
                );
", but the resultat is the same.

Comment: What type of view is secretCodeFields?

Comment: secretCodeFields is ConstraintLayout

Comment: I had a problem also when I used chain in `ConstraintLayout` that Id's of view's were not in correct format but I see you already use `generateViewId()` method which solved my problem, so I don't really know, maybe do some debugging and see what happens when you create that chain

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer but here it is

the `ConstraintSet.CHAIN_PACKED` will remove all applied margins to your views
you should first create the chain in Constraint Set then after that apply margins using the ConstrainSet `connect(int startID, int startSide, int endID, int endSide, int margin)` method to indicate margins.